# IndexError: list index out of range (face_image)[0]

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, index-error

```
known_faces = []
ROOT_FOLDER =""MYpartfile

known_faces_names = []
known_faces_encodings = []
for path in glob.iglob(os.path.join(ROOT_FOLDER, "**", "*.jpg")):
    path = path.replace("\\","/")
    person = path.split("/")[-2]
    known_faces.append([person,path])
print(known_faces)
for face in known_faces:
    known_faces_names.append(face[0])
    face_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(face[1])
    face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0]
    known_faces_encodings.append(face_encoding)
```

error
face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

i try

```
face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image[0])
```

but the data is not stored in the array

```
 print(known_faces_encodings)
```

This out put

[[], [], [], []]

Answer (score 1):

"*error face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0] IndexError: list index out of range*" means that no face has been recognized at the particular image, so resulting list is empty. The simpliest way to avoid the issue is to use

```
try:
    face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0]
except:
    continue
```

construction.